# iOS - can I use open source ResearchKit screens to make an arbitrary app?

Tags: ios, ios9, open-source, researchkit

I'm trying to create a survey-style app which would collect some information from a user, then process it and make a recommendation. It appears that [ResearchKit](https://github.com/researchkit/researchkit) comes very close to what I need in terms of assembling series of questions in a paginated layout.

I've looked at apple app store review guidelines, and the project liscence,  and can't find if I can arbitrarily take a portion of ResearchKit, build an app on top of it and publish it.

**Can I modify open source ResearchKit framework to build arbitrary kind of app on top of it?**

Comment: Read RK's BSD license.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can liberally use portions of *ResearchKit* code to build your app.

[*ResearchKit*'s license](https://github.com/ResearchKit/ResearchKit/blob/master/LICENSE) is *BSD*-like, so you can use *ResearchKit* code in any way you see fit provided you comply with its three points:

> 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
> 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
>      documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
> 3. Neither the name of the copyright holder(s) nor the names of any contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived from
>      this software without specific prior written permission. No license is
>      granted to the trademarks of the copyright holders even if such marks
>      are included in this software.

---

This won't probably apply to your case, given that you only want to use parts of the *ResearchKit* code, but if you want to advertise the fact that you app uses *ResearchKit*, you may do so as explained at the footer [here](http://researchkit.org):

> You may use the ResearchKit mark in order to indicate that your
>   product uses or is compatible with the ResearchKit software (for
>   example, “for use with,” “for,” or “compatible with" ResearchKit)
>   provided that:
>
> 1. The product does in fact use ResearchKit software developed by the ResearchKit.org open source project;
> 2. The ResearchKit mark stands apart from your brand or trademark (e.g., as in “ResearchKit for Chromium")
> 3. You do not seek to register a trademark containing ResearchKit or the  ResearchKit logo; and
> 4. You do not state or imply in any way that Apple endorses, sponsors or guarantees your product, or was involved in or
>      associated with its development.